# Enqueue in a minimum size queue

Tags: c++, loops, queue, task

I have a paradigm which has one queue per thread. I wish to find the minimum size queue, among the number of queues, which i did with the following code.

```
std::vector<std::queue<task> > q;

int min_value = INT_MAX;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=1; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
  if(min_value > q[i].size())
    min_value = q[i].size();
}
```

now i wish to do a additional operation in this, every time only the minimum size queue (found from the above code) should enqueue the task.

```
q.get (min_value)
q.push(task) // will this one, does the required operation?
```

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't have `get` member.

Comment: Your `for` loop ignores the first element of `q`, which is at index, 0. If you wish to access all your queues, you should initialize `i` to 0, not 1. Alternatively, consider using a range-based for loop: `for (auto& each_queue : q)` and then access `each_queue` instead of `q[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the smallest queue in the vector `q`. If so, you can do this:

```
auto cmp = [](std::queue<task> const & a, std::queue<task> const & b) {  
               return a.size() < b.size(); 
           };

//note q is a std::vector of std::queue
auto min_queue = std::min_element(q.begin(), q.end(), cmp);

min_queue->push(item);//min_queue is the iterator to the smallest queue
```

Also, I believe in your code, `i=1` is a mistake, which I think should be `i=0` if you want to search the entire vector, i.e from begin to end. If you really mean `i=1`, then you have to do this:

```
auto min_queue = std::min_element(q.begin() + 1, q.end(), cmp);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think OP really wants the minimum size queue, so he'd be better off storing the iterator returned by `std::min_element` and then using it.

Comment: @Gorpik: Oh maybe. Let me add this.

Comment: will std::queue supports q.begin(), q.end() operation? i think i saw this only in std::deque

Comment: @Dev: Learn about `std::queue` here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue . As you can see, it doesn't have `begin()` and `end()` members.

Comment: yes exactly thats what i meant too..!it doesn't have begin() and end() members. so how would you use it in std::queue ? just to clarify

Comment: @Dev: See YOUR code. In your code, `q` is a `std::vector`, not `std::queue`. The vector `q` is container of `std::queue`.

Comment: @Nawazsorry i thought you used only std::queue

Comment: @NawazYesterday i saw another answer with this code
`int min_index = 0;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=1; i<size; i++) //accessing loop of queues

    if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
        min_index = i;
// Now q[min_index] is your shortest queue` 
my paradigm is to start to check the queue from 1 to n only, so in this code will changing 
`int min_index = 0` to 1 will start the search from 2nd queue

Comment: @Dev: What does `1 to n` mean? `1` stands for first queue, or second queue? Note that arrays use zero-based index, so `0` means the first item. Also, `n` is inclusive or exlusive?

Comment: @Nawaz yes arrays are zero based, i need to calculated the sizes of queue, from the 2nd queue q[1], to the last queue q[n]. Because in my paradigm the 1st queue q[0] will be allocated with the task initially.

Comment: @Dev: Alright. You can use the second solution, which passes `q.begin() + 1` to `std::min_element`.