# how to access a vector of queues in two functions

Tags: c++, function, loops, queue

hi i have the following code which will find the minimum size queue among a vector of queues and the minimimum size queue will be used to `enqueue(push)` the int everytime

```
std::vector<std::queue<int> > q
void enqueue(){
int min_index = 1;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=2; i<size; i++) //accessing loop of queues
    if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
        min_index = i; // Now q[min_index] is the shortest queue
 q[min_index].push(int)
}
```

now my another paradigm is to do the dequeue(pop) operation in another function(shown below), bt i need to access all vector of queues declared in enqueue() function. how can i aceess the loop of queues given in the enqueue() function?

```
void dequeue(){

//q.pop operation , access all the queues in the vector of queues

}
```

will`q[i].pop(int)`; access all the queues in the enqueue function and does the pop operation?

Comment: Exactly same code here also (from the deleted answer which high-rep users can still see!) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382612/enqueue-in-a-minimum-size-queue

Comment: @nawaz i was about to comment there, but couldnt be clear with the formatting.. so only

Comment: it okay if you answer another question.

Comment: @nawaz do i need to follow this thread or the old thread.. sorry i dont know the rules of the forum

Comment: try to use priority queue to simplify your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MotherOfAllQueues{
    std::vector<std::queue<int> > q;
public:
    void enqueue(int);
    int dequeue();
};
```

Is there a problem with the obvious design?

Comment: or
`void dequeue(){
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=0; i<size; i++){
q.push(int)
}`
will this do the required operation?

Comment: @billa I thought that was a typo, isnt dequeue typically supposed to return the dequeued element?

Comment: yes it should return the dequeued element, did you see my updated comment? will that work?

Comment: @Karthikplease see this **Updated** one `void dequeue(){ std::size_t size = q.size(); for( i=0; i<size; i++){ q[i].pop(int) }` will this one does the required operation –

Comment: @billa depends on what dequeue means to you, do you expect to get the dequeued element? if not then void is fine...

Comment: i just checked my paradigm, i don't need to get the dequeued element. so will the above code work having a separate `for loop` inside the `dequeue()` function?

Comment: @billa Yes I suppose it will